# Parse.com Multiple Users accessing data - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am making a to do app using parse.com. I have got data which is set by a user and they should be able to assign that data to another user too. So the user sets a title, text and the name of the user they wish to assign it to. All of this is stored in the database and works well. When the same user logs in the data they set is displayed for him in the table view controller.

However the user they assigned to see the data does not display. So let me explain with code. The code underneath allows the user to see the data they set when they go to Table view screen. The code under is in the viewDidAppear function.

```
    func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore() {

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "toDo")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            var temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray

            self.toDoObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {

            println(error.userInfo)

        }

    }
```

With this, I have another function:

```
    func fetchAllObjects() {


    PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "toDo")

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)

            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()


        }else {


            println(error.userInfo)

        }            

    }

}
```

The user he wants to see that data to is assigned in the add new to do screen and that works. It even displays on the Parse.com database. But how can I query it or get it to show that data for the user who the data has been assigned to not just the user who set it.

So when (for example) UserOne sets data, it appears for him when he logs in and goes to table view, but even when he assigns to (for example) UserTwo and UserTwo logs in and goes to table view where the data is meant to be, I just do not know HOW TO DO??!

Please do help me or give me guidance, I am still searching on the solution to this, I feel like it is really simple but I cannot put my finger on it.

UPDATE *2

When the data is set, it is set with who the UserOne would like to give access to the data to.

So here is the saving process I guess:

```
    @IBAction func saveAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.object["username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
    self.object["title"] = self.titleField?.text
    self.object["text"] = self.textView?.text
    self.object["forUser"] = self.userToAssignTo?.text


    self.object.saveEventually { (success, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {




        }else{


            println(error.userInfo)

        }

    }
```

So then I tried to query the forUser:

```
    func fetchAllObjects() {


    PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "toDo")

    query.whereKey("forUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: nil)

            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()


        }else {


            println(error.userInfo)

        }            

    }

}
```

This still did not seem to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing now! Damn I just don't know how I can let another user see the data that one user has set.

UPDATE 3**

I found it! It was all about the viewDidAppear function, so here is the code:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

        var logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()

        logInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()

        signUpViewController.delegate = self

        logInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

        self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {

        //self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
        //self.fetchAllObjects()

        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore2()
        self.fetchAllObjects2()
    }

}
```

It is basically because the fetchAllObjects was kind of wiping it out for the "forUser" key. But now I need to figure out how to do it so the fetchAllObjects don't wipe each other off because it almost like a refresh button and then all the data is wiped off the screen.

Comment: Could it be a permission issue? Are you sure the second user has read-permission to read the object created by the first user?

Comment: Oh? Hmm, how do you do that, I think that that may be it! @piojo

Comment: I thought the default permissions were "everyone can read everything", so that may not be it. But you can check the parse iOS/OSX docs and search for "ACL"--I don't have a link handy, though.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted the code where you add the data intended for the other user. So be sure that's right. (Or post it.)

Comment: Look at Update 2, I edited my question @piojo

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's a permission problem. Something more basic is wrong, like incorrect data or an incorrect class name in a query... or something else unexpected. Does the right data show up in the Parse dashboard? And if so, can you write some dummy code to access it (where all variables are typed by you, not from text fields or from "current user.username"? That's not necessary, but it's the next thing I would do if I were solving this problem. Then, figure out how the two code cases differ.)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar issue however with push notifications from parse. I can provide code examples later today. There are a couple ways to approach. When the user creates a new to do you can set a custom object with the user they want to assign to and you can query based on the field. You can save the to do with saveinbackground with block. Another way is to use PFRelation. Watched a few courses on team tree house to review and see different techniques and they have one that is a self destructing messaging app that uses parse for functions much similar to what you want to do.

Comment: Ah wow, can I see some of the examples please? I'm still new to coding (only 1 month) and I need to understand with comments and code. I think I did try to do that by the way. I put it so the UserOne has to put in a title, text and the user they want to be able to see the data and I saved that to my Parse.com library as forUser. But When I query it, I just don't know how to. Look at the update I have in the question @jimrice

Comment: Yes I can provide some code when I get into the office later.  The website teamtreehouse.com is a great resource for starting out and the basis of your app is the same as the messaging app except the difference is the message in their example would be your to do. They have a 14 day trial and will walk you through a bunch of examples of using parse including users and relations.